# c++: problem while copying string into character array

Tags: c++

I am trying to copy contents of a file into fields in a class `courseInfo`.
this is the code im using:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<vector>
#include<sstream>
#include <bits/stdc++.h> 

using namespace std;
class courseInfo
{
public:
   char courseCode[8];
   char courseName[80];
   int ECTS;
};

int main()
{
   ifstream fin("courses.txt");
   if(!fin.is_open())
   {
      cout<<"file doesn't exist";
      return 0;
   }
   string line;
   vector<courseInfo> courses;
   while(getline(fin,line))
   {
      stringstream linestream(line);
      string segment;
      vector<string> segmentlist;
      while(getline(linestream, segment, ';'))
      {
         segmentlist.push_back(segment);
      }
     //cout<<segmentlist.at(0).c_str();
      courseInfo c;
      //segmentlist.at(0).copy(c.courseCode, segmentlist.at(0).size()+1);
      //c.courseCode[segmentlist.at(0).size()] = '\0';
      strcpy(c.courseCode, segmentlist.at(0).c_str());
      cout<<c.courseCode<<"\n;
      strcpy(c.courseName, segmentlist.at(1).c_str());
      cout<<c.courseCode;
    }
   return 0;
  }
```

content of courses.txt file:

TURK 101;Turkish l;3.

output i get:

TURK 101

TURK 101Turkish l

the contents of courseCode changes when i copy something into courseName.
why does this happen?
how do i rectify this?

Comment: Because the arrays you declared are not big enough. `TURK 101` is eight characters so needs an array of size 9 to store it. This is because C style strings have an extra *nul character* at the end.

Comment: its working now @john

Comment: Since you''re using C++, add `#include <string>` header and replace your char array with `std::string`, and use `std::copy(segmentlist.begin(), segmentlist.end(), c.courseCode.begin() )` instead of `strcpy`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note how `TURK 101` is exactly 8 bytes.
When you `cout << c.courseCode`, your program prints characters until it encounters a NUL byte. By accident, the first byte of `c.courseName` is NUL.
After you read into it, it is no longer NUL and thus printing `c.courseCode` happily continues into `c.courseName`.

Some options:

- The most obvious (and recommended) solution is to use `std::string` in your struct instead of fixed-size `char` arrays.
  However, this looks like a homework question, so you probably are not allowed to use `std::string`.
- Use `std::vector<char>` instead, but that is probably also not allowed.
- Make `courseCode` large enough to contain any possible course code, plus one character for the NUL-terminator. In this case, make `courseCode` 9 chars large.
- Use heap-allocated memory (`new char[str.size()+1]` to allocate a `char *`, `delete[] ptr` to free it afterwards). And then change `courseInfo` to take regular pointers. Ideally all the memory management is done in constructors/destructors. See the [rule of three/five/zero](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three).